# If $K/L$ is normal and $L/F$ is purely inseparable, then $K/F$ is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

This is a problem in Morandi's *Field and Galois Theory*, on page 49:

> Let $F\subset L\subset K$ be field extensions such that $K/L$ is normal and $L/F$ is purely inseparable. Show that $K/F$ is normal.